# how to fetch recent half timeline in date column

Tags: mysql

Question

> Write a Query to display the employee_id, first_name, last_name, department_id of the
> employees who have been recruited in the recent half timeline since the recruiting began.

My query

```
with d(dates)as
(select datediff(max(hire_date), min(hire_date)) as dates from EMPLOYEEs)
select * from EMPLOYEEs a,d where d.dates>d.dates/2
```

Im not getting the output pls help me

Comment: Break it down into chunks. First what's the query to determine the recent half timeline.

Comment: i dont know sir,can u tell me pls

Comment: Ok, so what's the query to determine when recruiting began?

Comment: order by hire_date ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM my_dates 
 ORDER 
    BY dt;

+-----+------------+
| id  | dt         |
+-----+------------+
| 139 | 2020-01-02 |
| 274 | 2020-01-02 |
| 277 | 2020-01-02 |
...
| 126 | 2020-06-18 |
| 182 | 2020-06-18 |
|  73 | 2020-06-21 |
...
| 293 | 2020-11-24 |
| 149 | 2020-11-25 |
| 343 | 2020-11-26 |
+-----+------------+
```

This sample data comprises a couple of hundred dates between 2nd January and 29th November (today) this year - a period of 332 days.

We don't store dates in the future, so the recent half timeline would simply be all dates greater than `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 166 (332/2) days`...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM my_dates 
 WHERE dt >= (SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL ROUND(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),MIN(dt))/2,0) DAY FROM my_dates)
 ORDER 
    BY dt;
    
+-----+------------+
| id  | dt         |
+-----+------------+
| 126 | 2020-06-18 |
| 182 | 2020-06-18 |
|  73 | 2020-06-21 |
...
| 293 | 2020-11-24 |
| 149 | 2020-11-25 |
| 343 | 2020-11-26 |
+-----+------------+
```

This query calculates the difference in days between the earliest date and today's date. It then divides this in half and uses that value (let's call it x) to return all dates greater than "today's date minus x days".

Comment: Thank u so much sir.Can u pls explain how this query works ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
DECLARE @HalftimeDay DATETIME =  DATEADD(dd, -DATEDIFF(dd, (SELECT min(hire_date) from EMPLOYEEs), GETDATE() )/2, GETDATE()) 

SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, department_id 
FROM EMPLOYEEs
WHERE hire_date >= @HalftimeDay
```

Comment: it is not working in MYSQL workbench,can u tell me using sub-query method for this question